# Create new fieldset row for legend

Tags: css, legend, fieldset

I have a Restrict Content Pro form which includes a fieldset legend (Change your Password) which I want to move to a new row in the left column. I have tried adding new form fields (to move the legend along) and then hiding them but that gets me nowhere.
Any suggestions?
[Change your Password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZ3QM.png)

Answer (score 1):

This is a demo :). Hope this work properly.

```css
fieldset {
  border: none;
}

input {
  padding: 8px 20px;
  border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
  border-radius:15px;
  background:#f1efd0;
}

input::placeholder {
  opacity: 0;
}

legend {  
  transform: translate(20px,30px);
  transition: all 0.75s ease;
}

input:not(:placeholder-shown) ~ legend  {
  color: #111;
  transform: translate(0);
}

body{
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="New Password" autocomplete="off"/>
  <legend><label for="password">New Password</label></legend>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: is working properly?

Comment: I already have css on the page which includes a table. I have copied the css to this page: https://era.org.au/css/

Comment: I should add that the form is created using Restrict Content Pro

Comment: Do you need any further info to assist?